# json_encode me da error [[]] con array multidimencional php

Tags: php, json

No sé cómo solucionar esto:

```
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
     $producto[0]=2;
     $producto[1]=1;
     $producto[2]=3.5;
     $productos[]=$producto;
}
$productos=json_encode($productos);
var_dump($productos);
```

Me resulta esto:

```
string(31) "[[2,1,3.5],[2,1,3.5],[2,1,3.5]]"
```

Y quiero que me quede esto:

```
string(31) "[{2,1,3.5},{2,1,3.5},{2,1,3.5}]"
```

Comment: Hola. No puedes utilizar json encode entonces. Tal y como lo pides no sería una estructura de un JSON correcta. ¿Podrías comentar un poco más para que lo necesitas? Porque parsear eso o acceder a datos será un problema.

Comment: Resulta que ese json lo estoy mandando con un insert a una columna de tipo json en mysql, pero me manda error de sintaxys, pero lo raro es que file_put_contents sí me lo escribe como quiero en un archivo json

Comment: Comprendo, pero mira lo siguiente. Tal y como lo quieres daría un error de parseo: `echo "[{2,1,3.5},{2,1,3.5},{2,1,3.5}]" | jq` Resultado: `parse error: Objects must consist of key:value pairs at line 1, column 4`. Tal y como te lo codifica en JSON la función de PHP `echo "[[2,1,3.5],[2,1,3.5],[2,1,3.5]]" | jq` resultado válido: `"[[2,1,3.5],[2,1,3.5],[2,1,3.5]]"`. Podrías añadir más info del tipo de dato de MySQL y como lo intentas insertar. Porque huele a que el problema es otro.

Comment: Lo envío con este código, el json va en "detalles": ```$mysql->query("insert into azx (tipo, usuario, detalles, monto, fecha) VALUES ('v',$cod,'$productos',$total,'$fecha')") or die($mysql->error);```

Comment: Ya encontré el error, la variable $cod no estaba definida, mejor dicho no existía, se me pasó, Gracias, si no hubieras dicho que el error no era ese no hubiera revisado las otras variables

Comment: Excelente entonces :)